# Java-accessible web service for translation?

Tags: java, translation

I now have a running Java program which only lacks of the final step,that is:

suppose I have a String1 ="Obama"
is there any online translation API that I could use to get the corresponding Chinese word back,and put it in another String2="奥巴马“.

I've tried BabelFish,but that doesn't seem to provide any service for Java program.

Thanks guys,really need your help here to find some translation API for me that I could use in my Java program.

Robert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try [Google Translate](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/)

Comment: I am bit newbie here,in Eclipse,should I click on (default package) and then import the .jar file?

Comment: copy the jar into say a lib directory in your project then right click on the jar in your project and add it to your build path (Build Path>Add to build path)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google API Translate Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/).

> Provides a simple, unofficial, Java
>   client API for using Google Translate.

Answer (score 1):

Because of Google's decision in May 2011 to no longer have a free translation service (er I mean to *deprecate* the translator api), I see that there is need for other answers to this question.

One such alternative I found is [Microsoft Translator Java Api](http://code.google.com/p/microsoft-translator-java-api/) . Just saying ...

Answer (score 0):

[Google Translate Kit](http://ggltranslate.codeplex.com/). Java Wrapper just released